# ArrayList total number of objects

Tags: java, arraylist

I've searched to see if i can find something similar to this and can't, but if somebody has seen this answered i'd be happy to delete the question.

I'm new to programming and i am using ArrayList's for the first time. I am trying to find the total number of tasks that my TaskManager would have. I am expecting the answer 0 as i havent yet wrote a method to add a task.

My Code is minimal as i have just started.

```
public class TaskManager {
    private ArrayList<Task> task;
    private int nextTaskId;

    TaskManager()   {
        task = new ArrayList<Task>();
    }

    public int getCount()   {

    }
}
```

Thought i'd say thanks, i've managed it now!

Comment: use the `.size()` method of the `ArrayList`. [Here's an example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arraylist_size.htm)

Comment: javadocs are your friend - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Answer (score 0):

Should use this:

```
public int getCount() { 
     return task.size();
}
```

Comment: So like 
public int getCount( int numobjects)  {
int numobjects = task.size();
}

Comment: @Liam Lawton you should't use like this:getCount( int numobjects) { int numobjects = task.size(); } but you can use like this if you want:public int getCount() { return task.size(); }

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TaskManager {
    private ArrayList<Task> task;
    private int nextTaskId;

    TaskManager()   {
        task = new ArrayList<Task>();
    } 

    public int getCount()   {
        return task.size();
        //calling this function will return the size
    }
}
```